# R legend colors don't match pie chart colors

Tags: r, charts, legend

```
library(RMySQL)
library(plotrix)
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 user = 'root',
                 password = 'password',
                 host = 'localhost',
                 dbname='testtable1')
rs = dbSendQuery(con, "

                 SELECT  `Answer` 
                 FROM  `ams` 
                 WHERE  `QuestionText` =  'Year of Manufacture'


                 ")
myData = fetch(rs,n=-1)

attach(myData)
count <- table(myData)

percentlabels<- round(100*count/sum(count), 1)
pielabels<- paste(percentlabels, "%", sep="")


pie(count, main="pie chart")
legend('topright', legend=sapply(percentlabels, as.expression), fill=factor(count))
})
```

I've created a pie chart of several dates. In the legend, I'd like to include the percent values.

The problem I'm having is that the colors in the legend don't match the colors in the pie chart. Also, I'd like the percent values to be preceded with a percent symbol (%) if possible. Here's how my graph looks so far:

[image]

Comment: I offered an answer below, but let me suggest you go with a bar chart instead of a pie chart here. We process height better than angles, and the chart doesn't communicate the differences  as clearly as a bar plot would.  The other alternative would be to check out the waffle library in R and make a waffle plot.

Answer (score 1):

I see two errors in your code:

1) in the legend statement, you have percentlabels where it should be pielabels.

2) you should set a vector of colors and call it both in the pie statement and in the legend.

```
Cols<-c("red", "green", "blue")
pie(count, main="Pie Chart", col=Cols)
legend('topright', legend=sapply(pielabels, as.expression), fill=Cols)
```

I'm on my iPad so I can't check it, but that should do it.

See http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-tutorial-part-14/ for a good tutorial.